# Redirect an old php file to a new URL using Nginx

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I have a website with URLs corresponding to PHP files:

```
www.mysite.com/cat.php?id=stuff
```

These PHP files don't exist anymore, how can I do a 301 redirect (for SEO reasons) to the new URL :

```
 www.mysite.com/stuff
```

I tried

```
 rewrite  ^/cat\.php\?id=stuff  http://www.mysite.com/stuff? permanent;
```

But it does not work, I get a "No input file specified".

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

More about my config (website is powered by Wordpress):

```
    index index.php;
    root /var/www/mydirectory;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you've added a `?` to the end of your rewritten directory, so nginx is telling PHP to serve `http://yourdomain.com/stuff?/index.php` which doesn't exist.

Assuming `mysites.com` was a typo and you're redirecting to the same domain, try this:

```
rewrite  ^/cat\.php\?id=(.*)$    /$1/    permanent;
```

There are a lot of issues with using `rewrite` and `try_files` together, I have a working config using these, something like:

I think the rule is that your `rewrite` rule has to come before `try_files`, so try this:

```
index index.php;
root /var/www/mydirectory;

location = / {
    rewrite  ^/cat\.php\?id=(.*)$    /$1/    permanent;
}

location ^(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$1;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Does this solution work? It should take whatever you pass to `id` and set that as folder so `http://domain.com/cat.php?id=xyz` redirects to `http://domain.com/xyz`.

Comment: It does not work even with the correct escaping. I still got "No input file specified"

Comment: No input file specified means that nginx is passing a non existant script URI to php-fpm. nginx doesn't check if the script exists before requesting from php. Does going directly to `http://yourdomain.com/stuff/` work?

Comment: I wrote: rewrite  ^/cat\.php\?id=(.*)$ /stuff permanent; But I still get the same error while the url /stuff does work

Comment: @JuCachalot - Have updated the answer, didn't notice you were using `try_files` too. These two rules don't play nice.